# Combining name columns LIKE another

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 name columns from table1.name and table2.name. I have names in table1.name like "Alex Testing" and in table2.name it's "Alexander Testing". I have the table do some other tricky stuff but it doesn't recognize that Alex and Alexander are the same people so it will not include the name in my report. I was wondering if there was a way I could get these 2 to inner join by first name or even by last name, like if another table had the same first name but different last name?

I've tried:

```
SELECT 
   Table1.[Name], Table2.[Time], 
   CASE WHEN myvariables here then 0 ELSE 1 END AS columnB
INTO NewTable
FROM 
   Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
      ON Table1.[Name] LIKE ('%' + Table2.Name + '%')
```

however it still does not work, it wont recognize Alex's name.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT 
   Table1.[Name], Table2.[Time], 
   CASE WHEN myvariables here THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as columnB
INTO NewTable
FROM 
   Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
      ON Table1.[Name] LIKE CONCAT('%',"Table2.Name", '%')
```

Comment: I would start from splitting this columns to last name and first name - so join condition will be pretty simple (either last names equals or first names, or even both). Otherwise making such a joins will be tricky and performance-wise expensive.

Comment: that's actually a sound suggestion. Kinda like have the 2 tables compare, join into a 3rd separate table using wildcards on the names?

Comment: Not quite sure why do you need some third table. As for me - it is enough to have separate Last_Name, First_Name instead of Name in your existing tables.

Comment: The problem here is %Alex Testing% isn't like *Alexander Testing*.  Name matching can be very tricky indeed.  There are many fringe cases you will need to take into account (Bob, Rob, Robert, etc).  The best place to start is a thorough analysis of all the names you have in the  two tables.

Comment: create one main table with names  and add Id of this column to names wherever the names are same.This change will be  lot better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 SELECT 
       Table1.[Name], Table2.[Time], 
       CASE WHEN myvariables here then 0 ELSE 1 END AS columnB
    INTO NewTable
    FROM 
       Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
          ON  SUBSTRING(Table1.[Name], CHARINDEX(' ', Table1.[Name]) + 1, LEN(Table1.[Name])) = SUBSTRING(Table2.[Name], CHARINDEX(' ', Table2.[Name]) + 1, LEN(Table2.[Name]))
```

If you have large volume tables you may want to use subqueries and select directly lastnames, and then use a join on lastnames.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 60
Incorrect syntax near '='.
That is the error I get

Comment: this did bring in some names that weren't there before so it did indeed work! However there are some names that are still missing so I may need to take the approach of separating the names as suggested in comments above.